# InvalidOperationException after promoting SharePoint server to domain controller

Tags: active-directory, sql-server, domain

I installed SharePoint 2013 Standard on Windows Server 2012, and it was running fine until I decided to make the server a domain controller:

- Remove the ADCS role
- Remove then re-add the ADDS role (not sure that step was needed)
- Promote to domain controller
- Re-add the ADCS role

Since then, when accessing `http://192.168.0.20/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/` I get:

> This operation can be performed only on a computer that is joined to a server farm by users who have permissions in SQL Server to read from the configuration database. To connect this server to the server farm, use the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard, located on the Start menu in Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products.

How can I fix this?
I don't have a farm, just one server.
Do I need to reinstall SharePoint, or create technical users in ActiveDirectory?

Stack trace:

```
[InvalidOperationException: This operation can be performed only on a computer that is joined to a server farm by users who have permissions in SQL Server to read from the configuration database. To connect this server to the server farm, use the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard, located on the Start menu in Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products.]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.AlternateServerUrlFromHttpRequestUrl(Uri url) +262
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAlternateUrl.GetContextUri(HttpContext ctx) +385
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAppRequestContext.InitCurrent(HttpContext context) +1013
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAppRequestContext.get_Current() +175
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.CreateSPRequestAndSetIdentity(SPSite site, String name, Boolean bNotGlobalAdminCode, String strUrl, Boolean bNotAddToContext, Byte[] UserToken, SPAppPrincipalToken appPrincipalToken, String userName, Boolean bIgnoreTokenTimeout, Boolean bAsAnonymous) +400
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRequestManager.GetContextRequest(SPRequestAuthenticationMode authenticationMode) +120
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.get_RequestAny() +370
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPLanguageSettings.GetGlobalInstalledLanguages(Int32 compatibilityLevel) +39
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTemplateFileSystemWatcher.RefreshInstalledLocales() +103
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTemplateFileSystemWatcher.Initialize() +130
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.System.Web.IHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +873
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +582
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +322
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +384
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +397
[HttpException (0x80004005): This operation can be performed only on a computer that is joined to a server farm by users who have permissions in SQL Server to read from the configuration database. To connect this server to the server farm, use the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard, located on the Start menu in Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +646
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +771
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a lot of content in your SharePoint databases? What is your view on detaching content database, remove SharePoint API, install SharePoint with fresh install and connect content databases again?

Comment: Definitely reinstall and Content DB restore! By the time you still try to figure out how to start fixing it, you'd have it reinstalled and restored.

Comment: I don't have anything important in SharePoint.

Comment: Then I would definitely do a reinstall. You don't want to troubleshoot some of the problems now, get it all working on the surface and two months later (and a lot of content and customization) run in to some more problems. Good luck no matter what you choose mate!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reinstalling just check if your SQL Server Service is running.
I had the same Problem and this solved it.