# How to force standalone install?

Tags: installation, database, domain

On out-of-the-box Windows Server 2012, I installed SharePoint 2013. I was not asked any database question, and SharePoint was working fine.

Then I made the server a domain controller and [decided](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60585/invalidoperationexception-after-promoting-sharepoint-server-to-domain-controller) to reinstall SharePoint.
Uninstalling was easy.
PROBLEM: When re-installing, I am asked:

[image: Specify Configuration Database Settings]

I have no idea what it means.
Can I make it as easy as the first time I installed? (= "standalone", not "complete")
If not, any idea where can I find these details?

I tried entering the server name `SPOON` as `Database server`, and Administrator credentials, but I am told `Cannot connect to database master at SQL server`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standalone install only comes up if you are not part of a domain. If a PDC or any other DC is installed on the machine where you wish to install SharePoint, the whole screen with stand-alone vs complete will not come up !

Found this out the hard way. Had to re-install from scratch, first installing SharePoint, then installing DC.

Arjan S

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is no way to force standalone install after uninstall (except reinstalling the Operating System).

I gave up and used the Complete install.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you installed SharePoint you probably choose to install a "Stand-Alone"  version which automatically installs SQL Express for you:

[image]

In 99% of the cases that's a bad idea. Go for  the "Complete" installation which requires a database server already installed somewhere. When you choose that option, you will be presented with the screen you mention in your question.

If you really want to have the "Stand-Alone" version again, remove the binaries and start the install again.

A nice overview of what you need to install SharePoint can be found here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee667264.aspx

A very good installation guide for SharePoint 2013 on a single virtual machine is available at Critical Path's website (register as member first):
http://www.criticalpathtraining.com/Members/Documents/SharePoint%20Server%202013%20Virtual%20Machine%20Setup%20Guide%20(v1.0).zip

Comment: Thanks for your asnwer! I guess I am in the 1% because the "Stand-Alone" version was perfect for me. I only need SharePoint to run compatibility tests. What does "remove the binaries" mean in addition to uninstalling?

Comment: Removing the binaries > just meant uninstalling :)

Comment: The problem is: the screen in my question appears at install, even though *I have uninstalled* SharePoint just before. I am not shown any screen to choose between Complete and Stand-alone.